# Debugging Azure Mobile Service Authentication

Tags: debugging, authentication, azure, mobile, service

I'm new to azure mobile services development and any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have created sample mobile service application and could successfully launch and debug it locally. As a next step I've added google authentication. Everything works fine when the service is Published and running in the cloud. But, I could not make the service to run locally so that I can debug the service for cases when the user is authenticated.

So for I have wrestled with IIS Express and made it work with HTTPS on port 44300. But Google authentication services complained because of redirect URLs mismatch, even though I've added `https://localhost:44300/signin-google` to redirect list.

I feel like I'm not doing something correct here. Something does not make me believe that debugging locally is not possible.

Thanks,
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to debug in localhost, but the google/facebook/Microsoft authentication should not be tested, because it is provided out-of-the-box by Azure Mobile Service team.

you should configure it in Azure Portal and then you should implement it in your application like documentation provides.

The following resources has the references to the Authentication articles: 
[Azure Mobile Services for Client Apps](http://curah.microsoft.com/267632/azure-mobile-services-for-client-apps)